# Create a web based application to create an interface beween PACS and PRIMERA device for CD and DVD burning

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hardware-interface, cd-burning

Respected All,

i have to Create a web based application to create an interface between PACS and PRIMERA device for CD and DVD burning.

How can i interact with my Cd Burning device through my Web application.

Comment: I hope that you mean that the Pacs and primera, is on server, and you wish to control it from the client - correct ?

Comment: Pacs(web application) is on server.....Primera on any machine over the network......Now Primera functionality is to scans the Folder created on my web app.. looking for .jrq file(job request file)...In .jrq file contains text information which data to burn how many copies of CD..etc..Now my aim is how to interact with web application to scan the folder present in web app....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that you talk 
You can use the sell command, or the process start, to send commands from asp.net to your server computer.

For the Process Start:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx

One more example how to Interactive command shell from asp.net

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18773/Run-Interactive-Command-Shell-or-Batch-Files-From

Comment: I am getting error when i run this application .............Error 2 Could not load file or assembly 'vjslib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) C:\Users\Fedora\Downloads\RunCmd\Web.Config 22

Comment: @user1179700 I really do not know, you can make a new question about it. Maybe its a permission problem, maybe is a web.config mistake